# SQL From key word not where expected?

Tags: sql, oracle, cognos

I'm using SQL in Oracle.  I have used aliases to pull back the same table more than once (but codes doesn't seem to read that far even).

I am getting the message

> ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected.

Any ideas why I am getting this message on the code below?

```
select 
T1."MORTGAGE" "c1", 
T1."ACCNO" "c2", 
T2."TIERRATE" "c3", 
T3."PRODCODE" "c4"
T3."MTRANEFF" "c5", 
T3."RECTYPE" "c6",
T4. "PRODCODE" "c7",
T4."MTRANEFF" "c8", 
T5."TIERRATE" "c9"
from 
"BEL"."ACM01" T1,           
"BEL"."ACM03" T2,       
"BEL"."ACT13" T3,       
"BEL"."ACT13" T4,       
"BEL"."ACM03" T5        
where 
T1."PRODCODE"=T2."PRODCODE" and 
T1."ACCNO"=T3."ACCNO" and 
T3."ACCNO"=T4."ACCNO" AND 
T1."PRODCODE"=T5."PRODCODE" and 
T3."RECTYPE"='PR' and T1."PRODCODE" in ('NOR', 'UF3')
```

Answer (score 2):

You re missing a comma after "c4", on the fourth line.

But, you should really learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The query should look like this:

```
select T1."MORTGAGE" as "c1",  T1."ACCNO" as "c2",  T2."TIERRATE" as "c3", 
       T3."PRODCODE" as "c4", T3."MTRANEFF" as "c5", T3."RECTYPE" as "c6",
       T4. "PRODCODE" as "c7", T4."MTRANEFF" as "c8",  T5."TIERRATE" as "c9"
from "BEL"."ACM01" T1 join          
     "BEL"."ACM03" T2
     on T1."PRODCODE" = T2."PRODCODE" join
     "BEL"."ACT13" T3
     on T1."ACCNO" = T3."ACCNO" join
     "BEL"."ACT13" T4
     on T3."ACCNO" = T4."ACCNO" join    
     "BEL"."ACM03" T5        
     on T1."PRODCODE" = T5."PRODCODE" 
where T3."RECTYPE" = 'PR' and T1."PRODCODE" in ('NOR', 'UF3');
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use `as` for defining column aliases.  This habit can help spot errors when leaving out commas.
- Don't bother to put column names between double quotes.  It just makes queries harder to read.  Choose column names that don't need to be escaped.
- Give you tables aliases that make sense.  Just enumerating `T1`, `T2`, etc. doesn't provide much information to someone reading the query.

Comment: never and always are fun words - most Oracle users write their SQL exactly as the poster has with no problems. his issue is a missing comma, and only the missing comma.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - the rest is perhaps subjective (although everything Gordon said has very strong objective reasons), but the statement that "most Oracle users write their SQL exactly as the poster has with no problems" is false, twice over. Most Oracle users , and (almost) all the good ones, write SQL the way Gordon suggested; and those who don't run into frequent problems, witness the very large number of questions on this forum and similar ones where the problem is caused exactly by violating the simple rules Gordon has offered.

Comment: @mathguy false? I guess I just work and talk with the bad ones.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - Or maybe we have a different definition for "problem". In my opinion having to maintain or debug code like the one above, with non-standard names in double quotes, table names like t1, t2, t3, t4 and t5, etc., is a problem already.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - Also, I noticed on your profile that you work for Oracle. But you say "you just work... with the bad ones." Does that mean people at Oracle use the old, Oracle-style join syntax, while they tell all of us to use the SQL standard syntax?  :-)

Comment: @mathguy oh I hate the generic aliased columns, that's not very useful. quoted object names, hate even more. I don't AS my aliases, i use leading commas on lists so missing ones are easy to spot. Most customers I run into use oracle style JOIN syntax. there are a lot of us here, probably telling customers different things based on the scenarios. I usually defer to Tom https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:13430766143199

Comment: Thanks All, the query is actually written for me by clicking icons on the Cognos system I'm using and therefore the standard table names etc are added for me but I take you comments on board.  Never spotted the missing comma - doh!  However on correcting this the message  persisted so I ended up taking out two extracts and combining them in SAS

Comment: PS I also tried copying in your SQL Gordon Linoff which also wouldn't run.  Suddenly cognos didn't recognise the table ACM01 - I fear it may have more to do with cognos then your code?!

Comment: @Emma . . . I have no idea where your tables are. This answer is based on your question.

Comment: I appreciate that Gordon :)